# Tried to settimeout value for javascript but not working

Tags: javascript, settimeout

it is executing too fast.  I wanted to allow time to type on the keyboard before this kicks in.

```
"use strict";

let CustomerOptions = {
    itemInputId: 'txtSearch',
    url: 'api/Customers?contains=',
    size: 6,
    incrementalSearch: true,
    focusElementAfterSearch: 'listviewDNB_Mem_ITEM_0',
    onItemListBlur: function (text, value) {
        let targetValueElement =
        document.getElementById('hiddenCustomerNumber');
        targetValueElement.value = value;          
    },
    onItemListDisplay: function (text, value) {
        return value;  
    }      
}

ms.dom.documentReady(
    setTimeout(function () {
        new ms.AutoComplete(CustomerOptions);
    }, 30000)
);
```

Comment: what other language is this - doesn't look like native js

Comment: I'm afraid your question isn't complete.  (Actually, it's not even a question).  What behavior are you getting that you don't want?  What is the behavior you do want?  What is your question, exactly?

Comment: 30000 is 30 seconds. Is it too long?

Comment: @Pete It looks like regular JavaScript to me, although `ms.dom.documentReady` doesn't sound like the name of a function that would expect a timeoutId as an argument.

Comment: It is not waiting at all.  It just is not executing the settimeout.  It is executing the Autocomplete without wating 30 seconds.

Comment: It is javascript

Comment: ms.dom is another javascript file ms.dom.js that gets called with values from this javascript.

Comment: "use strict";
let CustomerOptions = {
    itemInputId: 'txtSearch',
    url: 'api/Customers?contains=',
    size: 6,
    incrementalSearch: true,
    focusElementAfterSearch: 'listviewDNB_Mem_ITEM_0',
      onItemListDisplay: function (text, value) {
        return value;  
    }
 
}  ms.dom.documentReady(
    function () {
         new ms.AutoComplete(CustomerOptions);
     } );

Comment: Just need to slow it down so when a user is typing on the keyboard it wont go immediately into this dropdown.

Comment: Any Help would really be appreciated?

Comment: You need to provide more context. Which library this is? A sample response from your backend, and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; - setTimeout() is being executed before documentReady() is.

documentReady looks like an event - and events usually receive a callback function.  But what you're doing is passing the result from setTimeout as the parameter to documentReady().

Effectively, your code works like this:

```
var to = setTimeout(function() {
   new ms.AutoComplete(CustomerOptions);
}, 30000)
ms.dom.documentReady(to)
```

does `CustomerOptions` even exist before documentReady()?

Comment: "use strict";
let CustomerOptions = {
    itemInputId: 'txtSearch',
    url: 'api/Customers?contains=',
    size: 6,
    incrementalSearch: true,
    focusElementAfterSearch: 'listviewDNB_Mem_ITEM_0',
      onItemListDisplay: function (text, value) {
        return value;  
    }
 
}  ms.dom.documentReady(
    function () {
         new ms.AutoComplete(CustomerOptions);
     } );

Comment: just needed to slow down CustomerOptions this is where they are typing in a value on the keyboard.  It comes up too fast.

Comment: Could you put that code into your original post?  It's hard to read in the comments.

Comment: I did but still a little messy.